# JavaScript for If Statement Inside For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to to return a new array of names of the people who are 16 or older.

```
const examplePeopleArray = [
        { name: 'John', age: 14 },
        { name: 'Joey', age: 16 },
        { name: 'Jane', age: 18 }
      ];

function getNamesOfLegalDrivers(people) {
    let legalDriver = []
        for (let i = 0; i > People.length; i++){
        if ( i >= 1){
    legalDriver += people.name.push(i)
        } else {
        legalDriver += i
    }
        }
    return legalDriver;
    }
    console.log(getNamesOfLegalDrivers(examplePeopleArray))
```

Comment: just use array.filter and to get names, use array.map, ex: examplePeopleArray.filter(p => p.age >=16).map(p => p.name);

Answer (score 3):

Just use array.filter and array.map, here is the snippet:

```
const examplePeopleArray = [
        { name: 'John', age: 14 },
        { name: 'Joey', age: 16 },
        { name: 'Jane', age: 18 }
      ];

let legalDriverNames = examplePeopleArray.filter(p => p.age >=16).map(p => p.name);

console.log(legalDriverNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter and map the names.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'John', age: 14 }, { name: 'Joey', age: 16 }, { name: 'Jane', age: 18 }],
    result = array
        .filter(({ age }) => age >= 16)
        .map(({ name }) => name)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that this line:

`for (let i = 0; i > People.length; i++){`

Should be:

`for (let i = 0; i > people.length; i++){`

(Lower case "people")

But as another user commented, using the `.filter()` method would be much simpler:

`examplePeopleArray.filter(person => person.age >= 16)`

That returns a new array with all items in the `examplePeopleArray` for which `person.age >= 16` returns true.

Comment: Oh! that was a typo.Thank you